# Git clone works fine but git push doesn't

Tags: git

I have created a test git repo on Git server:

```
/var/cache/git/username/myGitRepo.git
```

Which is a 'bare' git repo. The ownership of the files belong to this 'username' user. I can clone the above Git repo, on another Windows machine.

```
git clone git://myhost/var/cache/git/username/myGitRepo.git
```

The repo clones correctly. Then I can do local commits and try to push the changes back to my Git server:

```
git push origin master
```

But that gives a permission error on the server:

```
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /git/username/myGitRepo.git
```

I added the magic file '`git-daemon-export-ok`' file in the repo dir. But I keep getting the above error.

I even set the `chmod` to `777` of the `/var/cache/git/username/myGitRepo.git`

Getting same error.

Git remote -v throwing following output.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git://myhost/git/username/myGitRepo.git (fetch)
origin  git://myhost/git/username/myGitRepo.git (push)
```

Anyone could help me to get this error resolved?

Comment: Can you show us the result of `git remote -v` run in your working copy?  Are there any options associated with the ssh key installed in `username`'s `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: Thanks for the attention....I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You say that you cloned from `ssh://myhost/var/cache/git/username/myGitRepo.git` but the output of `git remote -v` clearly shows `git://` URLs, which are typically read-only.  Would you please repeat the clone operation *exactly as you present it in this question*, re-run `git remote -v`, and see what the URLs look like?

Comment: I apologies for typo..I am using the `git` protocol to clone.

Comment: I am using "Github for Windows" and had similar issue when switched between two Github accounts. Here's my solution:        
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565876/cannot-access-remote-git-repository/31010578#31010578

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Out of the box, the standard `git-daemon` does not allow you to `push` into repositories.  [The man page says](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon#_description):

> This is ideally suited for read-only updates, i.e., pulling from git repositories.

If you really want to enable anonymous `push` (and really, you don't; just use `ssh`), you need to enable the `receive-pack` service, which is disabled by default (because it's a bad idea).  Again, from the man page ([the **SERVICES** section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon#_services)):

> receive-pack
>
> This serves git send-pack clients, allowing anonymous
> push. **It is disabled by default, as there is no authentication in
> protocol** (in other words, anybody can push anything into the
> repository, including removal of refs).

The **bold** is mine.  You can enable this service globally by passing the `--enable=receive-pack` command line option, or per-repository by setting `daemon.receivepack` to `true` in your repository's git configuration.

Comment: what do you mean by "anonymus push"?

Comment: That's not my phrasing, that's a quote from the man page.  Typically, "anonymous" means "without authentication", which follows from the next sentence in that quote: "It is disabled by default, as there is no authentication in protocol (in other words, anybody can push anything into the repository, including removal of refs)."

Comment: and why would there be an authentication problem if I can clone the project with my ssh key which proves that I can authenticate just fine. I'm confused.

Comment: @m4l490n I have no idea what you're talking about...I don't believe you're the person who asked the question to which this is the answer, so I have no idea what issue you're experiencing or whether or not this answer applies to your situation. Please feel free to post a new question here and I'm happy to take a look at it.

Comment: for what is worth, I discovered the issue. I compared the .git/config with another one of my repos that is working fine on the push origin master and it turns out that the one having problems was pointing to an incorrect URL, so problem solved.